# Web authentication through C program

Tags: c, authentication, libcurl

First of all, the goals are not security nor user-friendliness. (Meaning no visual crap and no password encoding/ mega security stuff)

Server-side I want the simplest thing possible. Just a way to authenticate some ~5 users but knowing who they are when they do. Once they are authenticated I'll serve them a file (I haven't decided yet what, .txt or xml or something) and they won't be able to do anything else.

So from the program standpoint, I need to connect to my server, authenticate somehow, get a file, and disconnect. The user only interacts with the program with a simple user/pass combo. The rest is automatic. I was looking to libcurl for the connection+authentication+download, but I would like to hear suggestions because from this list: [libcurl competitors](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html), there seems to be much offer available.

I think of it as the same as when I do `sudo aptitude install`, but the sudo part would go on the server if that makes any sense.

So my question is, how can I make a page with an authentication (note that it doesn't have to have any visual output) which then lets the program download a file. And how do I connect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing possible would be to keep the path to the files secret and authenticating people by giving them the link.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this page on [HTTP Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) useful. You can either roll your own HTTP server or configure an existing httpd. Then, you can write a simple shell script that calls out to curl to authenticate and download the page.

Comment: Assuming I had a popular thing like Apache, how would I go about that? I guess all I can do in a shell script I can do in my C program right?

Answer (score 0):

If your users can have accounts on the server, a way would be to use the `scp` command. They will be prompted for their password. You can wrap it in a shell script or call it from a C program using `system` or equivalent.

**Edit:** Then you may look into protecting a directory by a `.htaccess` and a `.htpsswd`. I don't know it is accessible through `libcurl` or any other C library though.

Comment: The goal was they would be "registered" but not with actual accounts on the server.